# What does replace do if no match is found? (under the hood)

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, replace

I have very long strings that need to have a pattern removed if it appears. But it's an incredibly rare edge case for it to appear in the strings.

If I do this:

```
str = str.replace("pattern", "");
```

Then it looks like I'm **creating a new string** (because Java strings are immutable), which would be a waste if the original string was fine. Should I first check for a match, and then only replace if a match is found?

Comment: `What does replace do if no match is found?` Ans; It prints the original string as it is.

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes indeed. Did you read to the end?

Comment: One version of `String.java` I found appears to go through the regex pattern matcher to implement `replace()`, even though there's no regex involved.  It seems like this could make things a bit slower, but you'd have to benchmark it to be sure, and the answer may vary between JVM's.  In any event, do **not** count on the result of `replace` being `==` or `!=` to the original string, since the javadocs don't specify.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Short answer

Checking the documentation of various implementations, none seems to require the `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` method to return the same string if no match is found.

**Without the requirement from the documentation, the implementation may or may not optimize the method in the case no match is found.** It is best to write your code as if there is no optimization, to make sure that it runs correctly on any implementation or version of JRE.

In particular, when no match is found, Oracle's implementation (version 8-b123) returns the same String object, while GNU Classpath (version 0.95) returns a new String object regardless.

<sub>**If you can find any clause in any of the documentation requiring `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` to return the same `String` object when no match is found, please leave a comment.**</sub>

### Long answer

> The long answer below is to show that different implementation may or may not optimize the case where no match is found.

Let us look at Oracle's implementation and GNU Classpath's implementation of `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` method.

#### GNU Classpath

> **Note**: This is correct as of the time of writing. While the link is not likely to change in the future, the content of the link is likely to change to a newer version of GNU Classpath and may go out of sync with the quoted content below. If the change affects the correctness, please leave a comment.

Let us look at GNU Classpath's implementation of [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/String-source.html#line.1949) (version 0.95 quoted).

```
public String replace (CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
{
    String targetString = target.toString();
    String replaceString = replacement.toString();
    int targetLength = target.length();
    int replaceLength = replacement.length();

    int startPos = this.indexOf(targetString);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(this);    
    while (startPos != -1)
    {
        // Replace the target with the replacement
        result.replace(startPos, startPos + targetLength, replaceString);

        // Search for a new occurrence of the target
        startPos = result.indexOf(targetString, startPos + replaceLength);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Let us check the source code of [`StringBuilder.toString()`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StringBuilder-source.html#line.981). Since this decides the return value, if `StringBuilder.toString()` copies the buffer, then we don't need to further check any code above.

```
/**
 * Convert this <code>StringBuilder</code> to a <code>String</code>. The
 * String is composed of the characters currently in this StringBuilder. Note
 * that the result is a copy, and that future modifications to this buffer
 * do not affect the String.
 *
 * @return the characters in this StringBuilder
 */

public String toString()
{
    return new String(this);
}
```

If the documentation doesn't manage to persuade you, just follow the `String` constructor. Eventually, the non-public constructor [`String(char[], int, int, boolean)`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/String-source.html#line.537) is called, with the `boolean dont_copy` set to `false`, which means that the new `String` must copy the buffer.

```
 589:   public String(StringBuilder buffer)
 590:   {
 591:       this(buffer.value, 0, buffer.count);
 592:   }

 245:   public String(char[] data, int offset, int count)
 246:   {
 247:       this(data, offset, count, false);
 248:   }

 594:   /**
 595:    * Special constructor which can share an array when safe to do so.
 596:    *
 597:    * @param data the characters to copy
 598:    * @param offset the location to start from
 599:    * @param count the number of characters to use
 600:    * @param dont_copy true if the array is trusted, and need not be copied
 601:    * @throws NullPointerException if chars is null
 602:    * @throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException if bounds check fails
 603:    */
 604:   String(char[] data, int offset, int count, boolean dont_copy)
 605:   {
 606:       if (offset < 0)
 607:           throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset: " + offset);
 608:       if (count < 0)
 609:           throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("count: " + count);
 610:       // equivalent to: offset + count < 0 || offset + count > data.length
 611:       if (data.length - offset < count)
 612:           throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset + count: "
 613:                                                   + (offset + count));
 614:       if (dont_copy)
 615:       {
 616:           value = data;
 617:           this.offset = offset;
 618:       }
 619:       else
 620:       {
 621:           value = new char[count];
 622:           VMSystem.arraycopy(data, offset, value, 0, count);
 623:           this.offset = 0;
 624:       }
 625:       this.count = count;
 626:   }
```

These evidences suggest that GNU Classpath's implementation of `String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)` does not return the same string.

#### Oracle

In Oracle's implementation [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29) (version 8-b123 quoted), the method makes use of `Pattern` class to do the replacement.

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

[`Matcher.replaceAll(String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) call `toString()` function on `CharSequence` and return it when no match is found:

```
public String replaceAll(String replacement) {
    reset();
    boolean result = find();
    if (result) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        do {
            appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
            result = find();
        } while (result);
        appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

`String` implements the [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) interface, and since the String passes itself into the `Matcher`, let us look at [`String.toString`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/String.java#String.toString%28%29):

```
public String toString() {
    return this;
}
```

From this, we can conclude that Oracle's implementation returns the same String when no match is found.

Comment: Interesting observation. +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

I have not found a definitive answer (from the docs), but I tried this out on Oracle's JRE7 and found that `replace` returned a reference *to the same string*.

Here is the code I used for testing:

```
public class NoReplace {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String a = "hello";

        /* Test: replacement with no match */
        String b = a.replace("X", "H");
        /* a and b are still the same string? */
        System.out.println(b == a); // true

        /* Sanity: replacement WITH a match */
        String c = a.replace("h", "H");
        /* a and c are still the same string? */
        System.out.println(c == a); // false
    }
}
```

But I'd be interested in seeing some benchmarks of `replace` vs `contains` to know for sure if there's any advantage.

Answer (score 3):

Ok..  In Java 8. This is what happens when you call `myString.replace()`.

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

`Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
                this)`
The target String is compiled as a *Literal* pattern. and `matcher()` is called on it by passing the calling stringInstance to it.

Now the matcher() method will return a new matcher here. Just note that the `text` field of the `matcher` will be the current object (`this`) i.e the String object on which `replace()` was called.

Next, in `replaceAll()` we have the following code :
       `boolean result = find();`

i.e.,

```
public String replaceAll(String replacement) {
    reset();
    boolean result = find();  --> returns false. 
    if (result) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        do {
            appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
            result = find();
        } while (result);
        appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return text.toString(); --> same String
}
   if `find()` returns false, then ,matcher.text is returned which is the original String
```

Comment: Cool. Do you have a reference from the Java spec?

Comment: @ColBeseder -   [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) is the reference from Oracle doc.

Comment: That's a reference to replace(char,char). That's not the method used in the question. The javaDoc of replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) doesn't specify the required behavior in this case.

Comment: Eran is right--the behavior in your #1 is not guaranteed and may change with a future JRE.

Comment: Answer updated.. The Eventual result is the same.. i.e, The Same String will be returned.